# Access count() return zero. Don't know how to left join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, count, zero

I've got this query ready:

```
SELECT s.clubnr, sum(iif(s1.positie = "KP", 1, 0 )) AS AantalKeepers
FROM Selectie AS s, Speler AS s1, club c
WHERE s.spelernr = s1.spelernr
AND s.clubnr = c.clubnr
GROUP BY s.clubnr;
```

It returns the following result:

```
clubnr  AantalKeepers
1            4
2            5
3            3
4            4
5            3
6            4
7            3
8            2
9            3
10           3
11           3
12           4
13           4
14           4
15           3
16           3
17           3
18           3
```

It count's players from a club who have the position "KP" but the problem is that the results give me only the clubs with those players.

I've got 22 clubs but the query gives me 18 in return. Because the other 4 clubs (19 till 22) don't have any players who are "KP". So I need to get those clubs as well and then the query t return 0.

I've looked in the forum and saw the LEFT JOIN in a couple of threads. This is a level of Acces SQL which I don't understand.

Is there someone who can help me with this? Been stuck with this for days and a fresh look on it would be appreciated.

For a better look here is the file where the query is in: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsat8m5orzpro63/Clubs.accdb?dl=0)
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSI SQL syntax. Not sure if Access needs some extra parentheses...

```
SELECT s.clubnr, sum(iif(s1.positie = "KP", 1, 0 )) AS AantalKeepers
FROM Selectie AS s
    LEFT JOIN Speler AS s1 ON s.spelernr = s1.spelernr
    LEFT JOIN club c ON s.clubnr = c.clubnr
GROUP BY s.clubnr;
```

Comment: I think it will be the same

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Of course acces gives trouble for it. It gives me the following error

`missing operator in expression: s.spelernr = s1.spelernr LEFT JOIN club c ON s.clubnr = c.clubnr`

Comment: I'll edit the post with sample data. Good tip thanks!

Comment: In MS Access, you need parentheses around every join block, like `FROM (Selectie AS s
    LEFT JOIN Speler AS s1 ON s.spelernr = s1.spelernr)
    LEFT JOIN club c ON s.clubnr = c.clubnr`

Comment: Thanks for the input but It doesn't really work. As I know it's hard to test without test data. Is it possible for you to check it with all the data in the file? I edited in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem can be solved by removing the IIF in the SELECT clause. E.g.

```
SELECT s.clubnr, sum(*) AS AantalKeepers
FROM Selectie AS s, Speler AS s1, club c
WHERE s.spelernr = s1.spelernr
AND s.clubnr = c.clubnr
GROUP BY s.clubnr;
```